# Help understanding residual vs covariate plots in linear regression when covariate is transformed

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, diagnostic

I'm self-studying stats and in the books I've studying there usually aren't examples specifically dealing with residual plots for polynomial and spline fits. This has be thinking about residual vs covariate plots in general, and I'm wondering if my thought process is correct.

Starting with a basic straight line regression. Plotting residuals against the covariate is supposed to help reveal if your model has accounted for the effect of the covariate.  If the residuals are evenly spread around zero then that points towards "yes".

Sometimes in linear regression, the covariate needs to be transformed in order to get a good fit as in the following:

**Example 1**, take following the model where y is logarithmically related to the covariate x

```
set.seed(9)
x<-sample.int(1000,1000, replace=T)
noise<-rnorm(1000)
y<-log(x)+noise
plot(y~x)
```

If all we had were the data x and y, a quick look a the plot would suggest that y is nonlinearly related to x, and we may try something like

```
m<-lm(y~log(x))
r<-residuals(m)
plot(y=r,x=log(x)) # residuals vs transformed covariate
```

```
plot(y=r, x=x) # residuals vs untransformed covariate
```

Since the new covariate is log(x), we can check the fit by plotting the residuals against log(x).  Such a plot shows that the residuals are pretty evenly spread around zero, so that our model may have accurately captured the relationship between x and y. This is what the examples do in the books i've studied.

I'd think that the alternative plot of the residuals against the untransformed covariate shows much the same--basically the model residuals don't display much of a pattern across values of the covariate x. This makes sense for two reasons. 1) All log(x) is doing in the first plot is just stretching out the x axis on the second plot. For this reason I'd say both plots show basically the same information.   2) No matter what you did to x in the formula, it intuitively makes sense, to me, that a good fit should show no real pattern when plotted against the original covariate.  (by no pattern I mean evenly distributed around zero with an even width (homoscedasticity).

So far the two plots i'd look at in this situation seem equivalent, my question is what do do when a plotting residuals against your "transformed covariate" is complicated, like in splines or polynomial regression.

**Example 2**

```
x<-runif(1000,min=-5, max=5)
y<-.1*x^3-2*x^2-6*x+10+rnorm(1000,sd=15)
plot(y~x)
m<-lm(y~I(x^3)+I(x^2)+I(x))
r<-residuals(m)
plot(y=r, x=x)
```

Here y is in reality related to x by a cubic polynomial and looking at a plot if y vs x may suggest such a model.  In this situation x has been "expanded" into three components for the regression so a simple plot of the residuals against the transformed covariate isn't possible like it was above. It seems like you'd need to look at each component separately and I'm not entirely certain how I'd interpret those three plots because all of the variables are related to x.

Instead, it seems reasonable to just look the alternative plot I discussed: the residuals vs the untransformed covariate x. And in this example the plot shows exactly what we'd expect suggesting its the right plot to look at.

If the residuals are "what's left over" after the model fit, then it intuitively make sense to me that a good fit should show no real pattern when plot against the covariate itself. This type of plot is also easily interpretable, so I'd say
this this plot the "right one" to look at.

So is this correct?  If so, why do so many example plot residuals against the transformed covariate?  If my assessment is not correct, then what are we supposed to look at in polynomial or spline regression?